# Append to a string in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to get a download URL using `curl` and `awk` and want to append something to that URL afterwards.

Here some snipped of my code:

```
IMAGE=$(curl -I -s https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest | awk '/Location/ {print $2}')
CHECKSUM="$IMAGE.sha256"

echo $IMAGE
echo $CHECKSUM
```

What I'm getting is that it is somehow replacing parts at the beginning.

```
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2018-11-15/2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip
.sha256/downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2018-11-15/2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip
```

I'm a bit helpless, because the following works as expected:

```
A="https""://abc.org/a_b/a.zip" # looks weird, but full URLs are not allowed here
B="$A.sha256"
echo $B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? or what's the exact requirement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hexdump your string, you see that is uses windows line endings (with carriage return):

```
echo $IMAGE | hexdump -C
00000000  68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f  64 6f 77 6e 6c 6f 61 64  |https://download|
00000010  73 2e 72 61 73 70 62 65  72 72 79 70 69 2e 6f 72  |s.raspberrypi.or|
00000020  67 2f 72 61 73 70 62 69  61 6e 5f 6c 69 74 65 2f  |g/raspbian_lite/|
00000030  69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 72  61 73 70 62 69 61 6e 5f  |images/raspbian_|
00000040  6c 69 74 65 2d 32 30 31  38 2d 31 31 2d 31 35 2f  |lite-2018-11-15/|
00000050  32 30 31 38 2d 31 31 2d  31 33 2d 72 61 73 70 62  |2018-11-13-raspb|
00000060  69 61 6e 2d 73 74 72 65  74 63 68 2d 6c 69 74 65  |ian-stretch-lite|
00000070  2e 7a 69 70 0d 0a                                 |.zip..|
00000076
```

To fix that, use

```
IMAGE=$(curl -I -s https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest | awk '/Location/ {print $2}' | tr -d "\r")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem apparently is, that your `$IMAGE` contains / ends in a trailing '\r`(carriage return). So you've actually appended ".sha256" as you expected to`"something\r.sha256" which when being echoed means.... `something`, cursor back to the beginning of the line, `.sha256`. Long story short, strip that '\r`. E.g:

```
IMAGE=$(curl -I -s https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latest | awk '/Location/ {sub(/\r$/, "", $2); print $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bash you can use substring replacement, ie. replace the `\r` in `IMAGE`var:

```
$ CHECKSUM="${IMAGE/$'\r'/}.sha256"
$ echo $CHECKSUM 
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2018-11-15/2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite.zip.sha256
```

or prepare for it in the awk part by setting the record separator `RS`:

```
... | awk -v RS="\r?\n" '/Location/ {print $2}'
```

Tested with gawk, mawk and original-awk. Surprisingly `busybox awk` removed it by itself:

```
$ echo -e \\r | busybox awk '{print $1}' | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
```

but for example:

```
$ echo -e \\r | gawk '{print $1}' | hexdump -C
00000000  0d 0a                                             |..|
```